# how to sign APK with google upload key der file?

Tags: apk, google-signin, keytool

after importing the der file to the key store as follow

```
keytool -keystore my-release-key.keystore  -importcert 
    -file ~/Downloads/upload_cert.der  -alias uploadcert
```

I get an error when trying to assemble release APK

```
trusted certificate entries are not password-protected
```

If I add

```
-protected
```

to the import, I geth

```
keytool error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: password can't be null
```

and if I pass the password after -protected I get usage help message.
not sure how to pass the password.

Any idea if I am on the right path to sign with google upload certificate der file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing an APK with an upload key provided by Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070168/signing-an-apk-with-an-upload-key-provided-by-google-play)

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem and password can't be null problem may be passed by editing the comment like:

```
keytool -keystore parkimayaz.keystore  -importcert -file 
~/Downloads/upload_cert.der  -alias uploadcert -keypass "yourpass" -
storepass "yourpass"
```

Another info I used characters like (',#,^) on the password part which gave me some errors.

also please take a look at [oracle keytool docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

Comment: And How can I get it ?? if I type after keytool -list it it says ::java.lang.Exception: The keystore file does not exist: /Users/myuser/.keystore