# How to generate a new KEYSTORE file for Unity based on App Signing Certificate?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keystore, android-keystore

I have enabled "Google Play App Signing" for the app that already existed on Google play.

Now I cannot upload new app versions with the old KEYSTORE (.keystore) file.

Should I generate a new KEYSTORE file based on certificate fingerprints (attached in the image bellow) and how?

**NOTE: This question is specific for the Unity platform.** (2018 Release of Unity)

[image]

The actual error message I get after the new app version upload is like this:

> Upload failed
>
> > You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
> >
> > [ SHA1: 9A:... ]
> >
> > and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
> >
> > [ SHA1: 36:... ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Google Play App Signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enrolled in App Signing by Play, it looks like you have opted to create an upload key (probably by creating a new keystore). From now on, you should sign the APKs you upload to the Play Console with this new key/keystore.
Note that should still be able to upload APKs with the old keystore. I can't see the full certificate fingerprints on your screenshots, but it seems from the error message that you're uploading an APK that is signed with neither the upload key nor the deployment (a.k.a app signing) key. Try to locate the keystores and identify the aliases you've used when creating the upload key and use those.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to note:

Once you enable Google App Signing you can't disable it ever again.
The app sign-in process looks like in the image:

[image]

So you need first to generate the Upload key, and Google will take care of the app signing key for you.

To generate the Upload key, from the `upload_cert.der` and using the keytool.exe I found the only answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070168/signing-an-apk-with-an-upload-key-provided-by-google-play).

I tried this and it it looks it is true:
**You can't sign an APK with the upload certificate in the Google Play Console.**

I recall I ended contacting Google support, and they provided a procedure how to create a new certificate, and after that it worked.