# cordova: build android debug mode vs release mode when uploading apk

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to upload my `app-release.apk` built with cordova client command line commands, but google play keep saying me that I built the app in debug mode.

Here's the step I used to build the apk (following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749607/1460529))

```
keytool -importcert -file deployment_cert.der -keystore release.keystore 


cordova build android --release -- --keystore=release.keystore --storePassword=ZZZ --alias=YYY --password=XXX

8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
```

Here's the Google screenshot error

[image]

Comment: You need to zipalign and apksign yours app

Comment: apk sign with what? is there any docs that gives the full process to create an apk in release mode? I thought it was `cordova build android` command, but it's not enough

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got this working.

Following this [link](https://codeburst.io/publish-a-cordova-generated-android-app-to-the-google-play-store-c7ae51cccdd5) here's the entire process to have the release apk to be published to Google Play Store

```
cordova build —release

keytool -genkey -v -keystore android.keystore -alias android-app-key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore android.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk android-app-key

/path/to/android-sdk/zipalign -v 4 app-release-unsigned.apk app-release.apk
```

Comment: Path to zipalign (on Mac, at least): $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign Switch out version numbers as needed.

Comment: Use apksigner not jarsigner