# Xamarin: how to use keytool to upload my apk to play store?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

I see many questions and answers and some seem contradictory.

I have an APK. It does say "signed".

I can copy it to my phone and it runs OK.

If I put it on my website and download it I get a warning that it might harm my device.

I have defined a KeyStore, Pwd, Alias and AliasPwd in the app's project.

When I click on Sign the APK using the following keystore details I get an "jave.exe error 2" and that's it. The APK is then corrupted.

Is there a definite procedure for doing this? (I mean like step 1, step 2, etc.)?

And what about zipalign? And what about the answer here:
 [Signing an APK with an upload key provided by Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070168/signing-an-apk-with-an-upload-key-provided-by-google-play)

Which seems to add many caveats.

What do I do with my release APK so it can be signed and uploaded to Google Play store (or even to my own web site to be downloaded without warnings)?

SO I tried using the Keytool and this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Did you apply the V2 Signature Scheme? I have never worked with Xamarin before. I think I cannot help you further than linking this (maybe you are missing this step): https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2

Comment: Oy gevalt. Yet another poorly documented step.

Comment: So I "migrated" successfully but...now what?

Comment: I use the GUI `Right-Click Android Project -> Archive -> Distribute... -> Ad Hoc -> Import... -> Save As`.

Comment: This did work, sort of. I did save as and there's an apk created. BUT Android will not let it download. Just says error.

Comment: On my phone no error, just no download. I can copy it from my Release folder and that installs OK. But not via downloading from the web onto the phone.