# Transferring Android App between Developers: Keystore and Upload Keys

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I'm replacing an Android app on a client Google Play account that was previously maintained by another developer.

I've got the following things to work with:

- a PEM file with a `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` block
- a upload cert (DER), from Google Play
- a deployment cert (DER), from Google Play

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any clear way for me to create a keystore to sign the app for uploading and Google docs are, well, Google docs.

It's not possible to get further information from the previous developer.

I've tried a number of things, most promising of which was `keystore -importcert` and then `-changealias`, but that just gets me as far as this error:

`com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key [the name of the key] from store "[the keystore].keystore": trusted certificate entries are not password-protected`

So at the moment I'm lost as to how to upload the new app, and I'm looking for some sort of recipe to sort this out.

This question [Signing an APK with an upload key provided by Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070168/signing-an-apk-with-an-upload-key-provided-by-google-play) seems to be close, but it never works through how to deal with the private key.

Comment: by reading the error message, i think you need to add password to your PEM file. try the following link and see it helps: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104949/using-keytool-to-export-and-change-password-of-certificate-in-a-keystore

Comment: In order to find out what's wrong you can use gradle's signingReport command.

On mac:

./gradlew signingReport
On Windows:

gradlew signingReport your key alias does not exist. In Android Studio, you can use Build > Generate Signed APK..., enter your key store password, and then browse for a list of key alias in the keystore.